# Wireguard powershell script not working only on Windows 7, rest windows OS working fine

Tags: powershell, windows-7-x64, using, wireguard

I am using following code to download Wireguard .msi version, installing and creating tunnel with .conf file but the issue is its not working on Windows 7.

Basically When I execute PowerShell Script on Windows 7 the issue is its not even downloading wireguard .msi sometimes and if it download then it do not get install.

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/q', '/I', 'wireguard-amd64-0.5.3.msi' -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru | Out-Null
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\WireGuard\wireguard.exe' -ArgumentList '/uninstallmanagerservice' -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru | Out-Null
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\WireGuard\wireguard.exe' -ArgumentList '/installtunnelservice', "$destinationConf" -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru | Out-Null
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (_"not working"_ declaration does not suffice).

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to use `-Passthru` then pipe to `Out-Null`.

Comment: @JosefZ done, the issue is its not even downloading wireguard .msi sometimes and if it download then it do not get install.

Comment: Use the [logging options](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html) for msiexec.exe so you can inspect that after your code has run to see what errors occured.

Comment: Where is a piece of code for downloading a `.msi` file?

Comment: Before this code we are using auth token -read-host, [pscredential], GetNetworkCredential().password
$source = "https://download.wireguard.com/windows-client/wireguard-amd64-0.5.3.msi"
$destinationWireguard = "c:\wireguard-amd64-0.5.3.msi"
# Create the new WebClient
$webClient = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()
# Download the wireguard file
$webClient.DownloadFile($source, $destinationWireguard)

Comment: @JosefZ any help?

Answer (score 0):

`$source = "download.wireguard.com/windows-client/wireguard-amd64-0.5.3.msi"` defines a local path. Use `https://` prefix to define a web source.

Self-explained by running following script:

```
$source = "download.wireguard.com/windows-client/wireguard-amd64-0.5.3.msi"
$destinationWireguard = ".\wireguard-amd64-0.5.3.msi"
$webClient = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()
$webClient.DownloadFile($source, $destinationWireguard)

$source = "https://download.wireguard.com/windows-client/wireguard-amd64-0.5.3.msi"
$webClient.DownloadFile($source, $destinationWireguard)

Get-Item $destinationWireguard | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

**Result** (note the self-explaining error message):

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\73673275.ps1
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the
path 'D:\PShell\download.wireguard.com\windows-client\wireguard-amd64-0.5.3.msi'."
At D:\PShell\SO\73673275.ps1:4 char:1
+ $webClient.DownloadFile($source, $destinationWireguard)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

D:\PShell\wireguard-amd64-0.5.3.msi
PS D:\PShell>
```